# Rails - explore data from a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple question.

Is there a way to see all your data that your receive from a query in Rails?

Example:

```
@persons = Person.find(:all)
```

Is there a way to see all data from @person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'pp'

pp @persons = Person.find(:all)
```

or

```
puts @persons = Person.find(:all).inspect
```

Also look at the gem unroller, it's awesome at debugging, look at

```
http://unroller.rubyforge.org/
```

for an example with debugging ActiveRecord

Comment: Thanks, this answer is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

open your shell. type in:

```
rails c
```

and then

```
p = Person.find(:all)
```

and you should see all data. the rails console helped me a lot of times to inspect data.

or

what do you mean with "joined data"? if you just want to see the data you could use a database browser like SQL Database Browser for sqlite

Comment: Ok, that works, but the problem is. I want to see also the data that is joined. But I don't see this. Do I have to write a query from this in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

pp @persons

Also you can install this awesome gem: https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print and use ap instead. In that case:

ap @persons